# No Service on new iPhone after updating to iOS 13

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

i am new to iPhone. My newly purchased iPhone 8 shows no service after a call ends while wifi is turned on (calling to someone, or someone is calling me either way no difference). This was working fine before updating to iOS 13 update.

Steps to reproduce.

- Keep the wifi turned on and mobile data chosen as LTE (4g).
- Make a phone call or receive a phone a call.
- After ending the call, In few seconds you will notice the no service message.

Few workarounds,

workaround 1: turn off and turn on flight mode (not practical always after a phone call)

workaround 2: always keep LTE (4g) off

workaround 3: always keep WIFI turned off and use LTE (4g) only

is there a way to rollback to previous iOS version until apple find a fix ?

Comment: What is your normal network coverage strength ? I mean how many sticks or dots out of the total ? Also, rollback questions have been there on this site itself, in case you're looking for it

Comment: I'd call your provider & get a new SIM. If this was a general bug on the iPhone 8 it would be well-known by now.

Comment: @ankii it always shows all the sticks. only after a call ends it shows full stick and in a second it says no service.

Comment: @Tetsujin true and agree, i did buy a new sim from the same network provider and reset network settings but no clue. i am planning to try a new sim from a different network provider to make sure this is a network level issue.